# Accessing Devise helper methods from CanCan, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

This seems like an easy question that I just can't wrap my head around.

Using Devise for authentication and CanCan for authorization on a new Rails 3 app.

How can I access methods defined in `ApplicationController` within the `Ability` class that CanCan provides?

a.k.a., something like this:

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # Guest user.

    can :create, Post if user_signed_in?

  end
end
```

where `user_signed_in?` is defined in `ApplicationController`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the answer you wanted, but it seems like you are wanting to mix code concerns that shouldn't be mixed.

Is it a good idea to access `user_signed_in?` inside your authorisation rules? ... Since authorisation is only concerned with what someone can do, and should not be concerned with if that someone is authenticated (or not).

A before filter (`before_filter :authenticate_user!`) on your Posts controller to check that your user is authenticated should be enough to do achieve your objective; Your authorisation rules can be run *alongside* the authentication check, rather than mixed up with it's code.

It's a layered approach :-)

Comment: You may want a user who isn't signed in to be able to read a resource but not be able to write it... That is more granular than `authenticate_user` will provide.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese The question doesn't stipulate an anonymous user with read rights to a resource as a requirement.